# Angular ValidatorFn returns, but does not block Form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-form-validation

I have build a Custom Validator for my Form, which returns expected ValidationErrors object.

```js
ValidateDirectory(clientId: string): ValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
            const ret: ValidationErrors = { isValidDirectory: true };
            if (control.value == null || control.value === '') {
                return ret;
            }
            this.service.getList(clientId, control.value).subscribe((res) => {
                if (res.technicalRetCode !== 0) {
                    console.log(ret);
                    return ret;
                }
                return null;
            });
            return null;
        };
    }
```

I proved this with console.log line, this actually logs my object.

The Validator is attached besides a Validators.required in `ngOnInit`

```js
ngOnInit() {
  ...
  this.fourthFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      dateipfad: ['', {validator: Validators.compose([Validators.required, this.directoryValidator.ValidateDirectory(this.clientID)]), updateOn: 'blur'}]
    });
  ... 
}
```

Problem is: the required Validator works as intended, but my custom Validator just logs.

I have tried quite a lot, like using `validators` with array instead of `Validators.compose`, tweaked my Validator method to set `control.setErrors(ret)` some other things, nothing worked.

I feel like there is quite a simple solution, but I just can't find it...

**EDIT 1:**
I created a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysyb9i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Explanation: the input takes any strings, on deselect the validation kicks in.
if Input is 'false' it should set input to invalid by returning `const ret: ValidationErrors = { isValidDirectory: true };`, any other string should be valid and it returns `null`.

Both results are logged on console, so you can check it. If input is invalid it should show a notification div below (not quite sure, just added it for this stackblitz to show)

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz that will replicate your issue?

Comment: sure, gonna take some time

Comment: @yurzui I edited my Question with stackBlitz link. It's the first time I use it, so have mercy ;)

Comment: Try this updated stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjgqex?file=src/app/app.component.html It works for me. Just one note, if your validator is async then you should put it to async validators

Comment: Thanks for your help! This helps for the initial validation, but after you enter 'false' you don't get the invalid flag. I didn't work with async validators yet, but it seems the solution is to do this validator async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using async validator if the code inside your validator is async.

```
this.fourthFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  dateipfad: ['', {
    validators: [Validators.required],
    asyncValidators: [this.directoryValidator.ValidateDirectory(this.clientID)],
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    put it here
    updateOn: 'blur'
  }]
});
```

The validator should return [AsyncValidatorFn](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidatorFn) interface where you should subscribe to observable but rather map to the value you want. Angular will subscribe automatically to your observable.

```
ValidateDirectory(clientId: string): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): 
             Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    const ret: ValidationErrors = { isValidDirectory: true };

    if (control.value == null || control.value === '') {
      return of(ret);
    }

    return this.service.getList(clientId, control.value).pipe(map((res: any) => {
      if (res.technicalRetCode !== 0) {
        return ret;
      }

      return null;
    }));
  };
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6otacp?file=src/app/validators/directory-validator.ts)**

Also please do note that **async validators are fired only when all sync validators return null**. So you won't see the error from the start because you have synchronous `required` validator in place.